# Can't parse date format with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a string "Thu Jan 01 01:32:49 EDT 1970" and trying to parse it with java.text.SimpleDateFormat

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf_date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        Date d = sdf_date.parse("Thu Jan 01 01:32:49 EDT 1970");
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

And get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 01 01:32:49 EDT 1970"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)ppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I can't understand, what's wrong?

Comment: are you really getting this issue?same code works without exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its a `Locale` issue, because the code worked for me. Try:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",Locale.US);
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/bEoBrG)